# How to dispose of usercontrols created by DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, devexpress, datatemplate

I have to switch between two Views in WPF. I have a DataTemplate that uses ViewModels to infer which View to draw depending on the ViewModel. In short:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ..:RedScreenViewModel}">
<...:RedScreenViewModel/>
</DataTemplate>
```

On a whim I decided to switch rapidly between views.. and the memory usage of the WPF app shot up to 2gb. Now you may argue that in real life no one will ever do what I did. But I would like to know how to free the memory that was allocated. Unload is definitely called, I have unsubscribed from any event handlers.
But it doesn't help. Does DevExpress or WPF have a property that can tell .NET to dispose of usercontrol? 
Ones I found for DevExpress but do zilch are:

```
DisposeOnWindowClosing
DestroyOnClosingChildren
```

The View that created are very complex, I have reorganized layout in efforts to save memory. But the same increase. 
Suggestions would be great thanks.

EDIT:
The destructor isn't called however...

Comment: WPF components do not have a Dispose() method, because they rely on the garbage collector. If switching views causes that much "waste data", then try to call `GC.Collect()`. Furthermore, make sure that really no reference to the old data exists.

Comment: Without seeing the implementation of your view/viewmodel, it's hard to tell why so much memory is sticking around. I'd suggest using a memory profiler to figure out what objects are rooted. .NET Memory Profiler is pretty epic (http://memprofiler.com/) and they have a free trail.

Comment: @RafaelGoodman I found out the problem but can't solve it :(
A third party library I am using, its ItemsSource binds to an ObservableCollection. Behind the scenes it subscribes to the INotifiedPropertyChanged for that collection. That subscription means Dispose is never called. One way I tried was to set the Collection I am binding to null. That fixed the problem but I hate that solution because it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you dispose of UserControls nested inside an ItemsControl (in this case: a ListBox)

```
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (this.listb != null)
            {
                for (int count = 0; count < this.listb.Items.Count; count++)
                {
                    DependencyObject container = this.listb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(count);
                    UserControl userControl = container.GetVisualDescendent<UserControl>();
                    IDisposable controlToPotentiallyDispose = userControl as IDisposable;
                    if (controlToPotentiallyDispose != null)
                        controlToPotentiallyDispose.Dispose();
                    controlToPotentiallyDispose = null;
                }
            }
            if (this.ViewModel != null)
            {
                this.ViewModel.Dispose();
                this.ViewModel = null;
            }
            this.listb = null;
        }
```

Note that listb is the x:Name of the ListBox to find items from.
Also, this Dispose() method should be in the xaml.cs and should be called whenever you don't need the view anymore.

HTH,

Bab.